# How to display a table of employee details based on gender selection by the user, by providing the user 3 radio buttons

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've created a table of employees in view, used json array to store the employees details in my component and provided 3 radio buttons named: all, male and female.

What I want is, when I click on all, it should display the table with all the employees. and when I click on male, it should display the table of male employees only and when on clicking female, it should display the table with female candidates only. can anyone help me adding events to the radio buttons with my requirements?

Here is my code:

Component:

```js
  selectedgender = 'all';
  employees: any;
      
  constructor() {
    this.selectedgender = 'all';
    this.employees=  [
      {"FirstName":"Karthik", "LastName":"Dobbaka", "Age":29, "gender":"Male"},
      {"FirstName":"Yashwanth", "LastName":"Reddy", "Age":28, "gender":"Male"},
      {"FirstName":"Shiva", "LastName":"Kondella", "Age":31, "gender":"Male"},
      {"FirstName":"Arthi", "LastName":"Bharadwaj", "Age":29, "gender":"Female"},
      {"FirstName":"Kavya", "LastName":"Gadadasu", "Age":27, "gender":"Female"},
      {"FirstName":"Kishore", "LastName":"Veldandi", "Age":30, "gender":"Male"},
      {"FirstName":"Shrinivas", "LastName":"Bandi", "Age": 34, "gender":"Male"},
      {"FirstName":"Sowmya", "LastName":"Dasari", "Age":26, "gender":"Female"}
    ];
  }
```

View:

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>Select</label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="all"  [(ngModel)]="selectedgender">All
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" [(ngModel)]="selectedgender">Male
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" [(ngModel)]="selectedgender">Female
    </label>
  </div>

  <table border="2px">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>FirstName</th>
        <th>LastName</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>gender</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr *ngFor=" let emp of employees">
      <td>{{ emp.FirstName }}</td>
      <td>{{ emp.LastName }}</td>
      <td>{{ emp.Age }}</td>
      <td>{{ emp.gender }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You has three aproach

1.-Using an auxiliar variable

Decalre an auxiliar variable

```
employeesFiltered=this.employees
```

split the [(ngModel)] in [ngModel] (ngModelChange) to call a function

```
<input ...
       [ngModel]="selectedgender" 
       (ngModelChange)="selectedgender=$event;filter($event)"
>
```

And the function filter like

```
  filter(gender:string){
     this.employeesFiltered=gender=='all'?this.employees:
               this.employees.filter(x=>x.gender.toLowerCase()==gender)
  }
```

And iterare over employeesFiltered

```
<tr *ngFor=" let emp of employeesFiltered">
...
</tr>
```

2.-Using a pipe. A Pipe transform "anything" in other

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterEmployees'
})
export class FilterEmployeesPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any[], args?: any): any {
    console.log(args)
    return args=='all'?value:value.filter(x=>x.gender.toLowerCase()==args);
  }

}
```

And you iterate over employees |filterEmployees:selectedgender

```
<tr *ngFor=" let emp of employees |filterEmployees:selectedgender">
...
</tr>
```

3.-Using a getter. That's you greate a function

```
  get employeesFiltered2()
  {
    return this.selectedgender=='all'?this.employees:
         this.employees.filter(x=>x.gender.toLowerCase()==this.selectedgender)
  }
```

And iterate over employeesFiltered2

```
<tr *ngFor="let emp of employeesFiltered2">
...
</tr>
```

You can think that the two last options are more "elegant", but be careful. The two options makes that the function (or the pipe) is executed several times along the live of the component. That's are less "efficiency". In this case is not a big problem (no body can detect this lost of efficiency) but you need take account that a pipe or a getter is executed several times.

Well, you can avoid using OnPush change detection but it's require another answer and this is yet a bit large

You has a example of the three aproach in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-aufyvm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). I put in the stackblitz a "console.log" to allow see how many times is executed each function.